# masonry append with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-masonry

I am using masonry in my rails 3.2 application 
I have these code on my index.html

```
 <div id="imageall">
<div id="albums" class="relative">
 <%=render :partial=>"images/images",:locals=>{:images=>@images}%>

 </div>

<div id="append_and_paginate" class="span7 wmzero" >
<%=paginate @images%>
 </div>

 </div>

<script >

   if ($('#imageall .pagination').length) {
   $('#imageall #append_and_paginate').prepend(' <div class="loadmore"><a id="append_more_results" href="javascript:void(0);">load more photos</a></div>');
 $('#imageall #append_more_results').click(function() {
  var url;
  url = $(' #imageall .pagination .next_page a').attr('href');
  if (url) {
    $('#imageall .pagination').html('<div class="span7 wmzero loady"> <%=image_tag("loady.gif")%>   </div>');

     $.getScript(url);
  }
   });
 }
 </script>
```

on my index.js erb I am using these code

```
 $("#albums").append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial=>"images/images",:locals=>{:images=>@images}) %>").masonry({  itemSelector: '.item'});
 <% if (@images.current_page < @images.num_pages) %>
    $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j paginate(@images) %>');
 <% else %>
       $('#append_and_paginate').replaceWith(' <div class="nomore">No more photos</div>');
<% end %>
```

masonry working well till I try to load more images its not working

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here
https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/374

var imgs=' <%= escape_javascript(render :partial=>"images/images",:locals=>{:images=>@images}) %>';

var images = jQuery( imgs ).filter('div').masonry();